# Youtube API forUsername Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I want a channel list for playlist from Music Channel of youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ), however I am getting error on the console, This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.get (
    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels", {
        part: "contentDetails"
        forUsername: "Music", //<-- the error is here? Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
        key: "AIzaSyCKhEoBd9nZsMAC77NKQqf403mXnXTz35s" }, 
        function(data) {
            $.each(data.items, function(i, item){
                console.log(item);
            })
        }
);
});
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 1):

You missed the comma at the end of the previous line.

The parser doesn't expect an identifier immediately after a string. It expects a comma.

Comment: I also like to ask, is it possible to list channel videos from other channel? i cannot access Music channel it is saying Forbidden access?